# Related to result of eager loading in ROR Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, eager-loading

I have an Invoice model which belongs to Customer (and of course Customer has_many invoices).

If I do:

```
{
  @invs = Invoice.find(
    :all, 
    :include => ["customer"], 
    :conditions => ['somecondition']
  )
}
```

The class of @invs is an Array and I can see all the attributes for the 6th invoice in the array if I do: `@invs[5]`.  However at that point I don't see the associated Customer record attributes.  To get that I need to do `@invs[5].customer`.

My question is what is the Ruby structure that allows access to the customer record from the invoice record?  I want to create a new arbitrary record of SomeClass and attach that to the invoice record within the recordset so that I can do `@inv[5].someclass`.  Is that possible? and if so how?

[EDIT - FULL STORY]
The following tries to explain why I'm asking the question.

Although my Invoice model relates to a single table in the Db my Customer record can get archived and moved to another table called Archcustomer which is identical to Customer in structure.  So I have additional associations like Invoice belongs_to Archcustomer and Archcustomer has_many Invoices.

I need to get a list of Invoices together with their associated customer record (regardless of where it's held i.e. Customer or Archcustomer) but sorted by Customer.category_id and Customer.id and Invoice.id.

In my original example above of @invs I am including the customer record and I could include the :order => 'customer.category_id, customer.id, invoice.id' clause but where the customer is archived the customer record is nil.

So I thought I would do the following:

```
{
  @invs.each do |inv|
    next if inv.customer != nil
    archcust = Archcustomer.find(inv.customer_id) #since it's not in customer get it from Archcustomer
    inv.customer.category_id = archcust.category_id 
    etc...
    ...
    end
}
```

and then use @inv.sort_by.  However that complains because I'm trying to allocate a value to customer.category_id of Nil class.

That's when I thought if I could attach an arbitrary record to Invoice I could fill in the info from either Archcustomer or Customer and have a  common set of attributes to call my sort_by on.

Of course if there is some other way of achieving my set of Invoices ordered as I want them then I'll be happy to go with that.

Comment: What exactly would you like to do now? Does `@invs[n].customer.customer_method` violate LoD too much, or are you after a polymorphic relationship?

Comment: @jimworm OK I was trying to save everyone from having to read the full story but I guess it's necessary to tell the story to understand what I'm trying to do.  So.... please see my edited post above.  Thanks for your interest and response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your invoice model (assuming you have your Archcustomer relationship in place):

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  def customer_record
    customer or archcustomer
  end
end
```

Use `@invoice.customer_record` instead of `@invoice.customer` or `@invoice.archcustomer` when you need to get a record from any available source. `.include` both when you're loading.

Don't bother assigning stuff to an imaginary `Customer` when you already have a real `Archcustomer`. Just run `sort_by` on `customer_record.category_id`.

Comment: Wow didn't know I could do that. I think I follow what you are saying but am not clear about ".include both when you're loading" comment.  Should I be  doing : invs = Invoice.find(:all, :include => ["customer","archcustomer"], :condition => ['someconditions'])?  More importantly could I include my :order => "customer_record.category_id etc at the same time?  Thanks for your prompt help.

Comment: Yes you should eager load both customers and archcustomers when you intend to use `customer_record`. `customer_record` isn't a real relationship class-wide (being an instance method), so you can't `order` it without some fancy SQL work and negating the benefits of ActiveRecord. Easier to sort it in Ruby.

Comment: Sorry I mixed some Rails 3 syntax in there when you're on Rails 2, but the principles are the same.